# Should this be considered as spam?

Tags: discussion, flagging, spamming

These two answers (from the same person) clearly promote pcbgogo, and the author is clearly affiliated (when you look at the profile, but it is not explicit when you read the answers). But it somewhat answers the question. Is that spam ? I don't want to flag lightly.

- [PCB fabrication vs PCB assembly](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111569/pcb-fabrication-vs-pcb-assembly/200092#200092)
- [PCB Prototyping and Fabrication](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55826/pcb-prototyping-and-fabrication/200091#200091)

Comment: Well, apparently, it should, considering that these answers have disappeared...

Comment: Also, to the mods around, maybe it would make sense to protect these two questions. I already flagged a similar (more obvious) spam two days ago on one of them. They certainly attract cheap fabs that want to advertise.

Comment: That second question doesn't belong here in the first place.  I just voted to close it as *too broad*.

Comment: @Olin The comment is not a question, but simply a suggestion. Anyway, the whole thing should indeed be closed for whatever reason seems relevant, there will never be any answer, and most people don't have the ability to see the original links now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *general*, you should flag answers like that as spam.

In *this particular case*, it seems as though we the moderators didn't deal with the posts (by removing the link or deleting the post). It looks like this was merely an oversight.